# Python 2.7 Script works in Shell but as a File

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've made a simple Script that tells you the Time. It works fine in Shell but when I try to run the File the Console opens and closes immediatly.

Here's the scipt :

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
print "Hello I am  Robot that tells you the time!"
print "Do you want to know what time it is?"
A = raw_input("Yes (Y) / No (N)")
if A == "Y" or "y":
 print "It is %s:%s !" % (now.hour, now.minute)

elif A == "N" or "n":
 print "Okay maybe next time!"

else:
 print "What do you mean by that?"

raw_input("press Enter to end")
```

Comment: Is this the whole file? How do you execute it? On which platform?

Comment: A == "Y" or "y" ? do you mean A == "Y" or A == "y" ?

Comment: YSelf I executed it in shell and as a .py File. The ladder didn't work. Ghilas I actually don't know the diffrence?

Comment: @GhilasBELHADJ just noticed what you meant and yeah that was wrong ^^'

Comment: they are totally different as "y" will act as if it's a statement itself. Change it as @GhilasBELHADJ fixed it. But this can't be your problem because you have another "raw_input()" before this line.

Answer (score 1):

In case you're having an exception and exiting before coming to `raw_input()` line, try this, it'll show your exception:

```
   if __name__ == '__main__':
        try:
            ## do your stuff here
        except:
            import sys
            print sys.exc_info()[0]
            import traceback
            print traceback.format_exc()
            print "Press Enter to continue ..." 
            raw_input()
```

if you want to keep the window open no matter the case, add this to above code:

```
       finally:
          print "Press Enter to continue ..." 
          raw_input()
```

Answer (score 1):

What I do in situations like this (with no errors) is this:
put a print() with a unique input after each line of code. you'll get to know which part causes the problem. 
It's not professional I guess, but it works for small code.

Answer (score 0):

I am so sorry for bothering you with this Question. As it turns out in the Programm there was an error that Shell tolareted but the Terminal didn't. 
I wrote

if A == "y" or "Y"

instead of

if A == "y" or A == "Y"